# how to accumulate values within a map function and store in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function which maps an array object of users with attributes `fullname` and `points`. Is there a way I can somehow add the points of every user whilst it maps and store it in a variable. I tried several ways with useState (in react), but I kept getting re-render error.

```
{users.map((user, index) => { return (
<tr key={index}>
  <td>{user.fullname}</td>
  <td>{user.points}</td>
</tr>
); })}
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in two separate steps.  Collect the points

```
const totalPoints = users.
    map(user => user.points).
    reduce((a,b)=> a + b, 0)
```

then leverage it in your code.

```
 { totalPoints }
```

In the UI / Browser it isn't likley to have too much data to be able to perform this with multiple loops, and IMO it keeps the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You should set points for every user using foreach in another method.

```
const Method=()=>{
const list=  users.forEach(function(user){
  user.point= 10;
    });
    setUsers(list);
    }
```